# How do we convert a Lead into person accounts in apex?

Tags: apex, lead-conversion

How can i convert a lead to person accounts using apex?
I have done lead conversion which would convert a lead to standard account, contact and opportunity by mostly referring https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_convertLead.htm

But i want to see if there is any way i can convert a lead to a person account? I couldnt find documentation on leadconversion for person accounts.

Any pointers to how to convert a lead to person accounts would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not that much of differ from the normal conversion. But keep the `Company` field of the `Lead` blank and convert. These are will be ended up with Person Accounts.

Documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=leads_notes.htm&language=en_US)

> Leads with a blank Company field are converted to person accounts